# Yahoo API の「パラメータが不足している」エラーになってしまう

Tags: php, api

Yahoo API の 日本語形態素解析 を実行しようとしています。

[Yahoo API 日本語形態素解析](https://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/jlp/ma/v2/parse.html)

コードは問題ないように思えるのですが「パラメータが足りない」というエラーが発生します。

上記の公式URLの他にこちらのサイトも参考にしました。
[Yahoo!のAPIで形態素解析](https://note.com/yukioterasawa/n/n1efbcf13035f)

コードは次のとおりです。

```
<?php

class YahooApiParse
{
    const END_POINT = "https://jlp.yahooapis.jp/MAService/V2/parse";
    const APP_ID = "(my API id)";
    const JSONRPC = "2.0";
    const METHOD = "jlp.maservice.parse";

    public function parse($text)
    {
        // Log the text being parsed
        $this->log($text);

        // Parse the text
        $result = $this->parseText($text);

        // Log the result of the parse
        $this->log($result);

        return $result;
    }

    private function parseText($text)
    {
        // $param の 'params' はオブジェクトにする
        $param = [
            'id' =>  time(),
            'jsonrpc' => self::JSONRPC,
            'method' => self::METHOD,
            'params' => ['q' => $text],
        ];

        var_dump($param);
        // Parse the text using the Yahoo API
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'User-Agent: Yahoo AppID: ' . self::APP_ID
        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, self::END_POINT);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
        $json = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        return json_decode($json, true);
    }

    private function log($text)
    {
        // Log the text somewhere
    }
}
```

出力されるエラー

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\web\text\class\YahooApiParse.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
array(3) {
  ["error"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(-32600)
    ["message"]=>
    string(15) "Invalid request"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["jsonrpc"]=>
  string(3) "2.0"
}
```

どの部分に問題があるのでしょうか？
何度見返しても、問題の場所を見つけることができません。
お力を貸していただけると嬉しいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

配列をそのまま送信していたのが原因でした。

次のように `json_encode` を追加することで解決しました。
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($param));`

ちなみに気がついたのは、chatGPTのおかげです。
コードを投げ込んでみると、上記の指摘をしてくれました。
スゴい